# Reliable/persistent timer in Flutter

Tags: asynchronous, flutter, dart, timer

In my application, it needs a timer to asynchronously launch a new UI screen when the timer expires. 
The following code shows the desired semantics:

`Timer t = Timer(Duration(seconds: myDuration), () { 
    askQuestion('How are you doing?'); }); 
  // Maybe later, before the timer goes off... 
  t.cancel();`

Using Timer, my implementation works sometimes, especially with small durations.

But when the duration is large, say 25, or 400 minutes, then my app would be killed and restarted, then the Timer is lost, the timeout will never happen.

My question is how I can make the Timer persistent surviving the restart of the app or reliable with some equivalent mechanism?

I may provide an ad hoc persistent solution by checking stored time value for the timer to expire at the (re)start of my program, and decide if I should relaunch the timer. But I'd like to learn if there is already a generic solution, as it's a general requirement for Future.delayed operation to survive program restart, otherwise, the use of Future.delayed is limited.

Otherwise, I might search for alternative solutions that provide persistence. I remember local notification might.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you should have to start timer when application started, but you also need to write time when you should show screen to cache service/preferences/db. Then if your application killed and started again you will start timer with rest time(because you need every time start timer on start and you know how much is rest).

Imagine that you should show screen every 400 min. Okay, from now is `DateTime.now().add(Duration(minutes:400))` and we can safely start timer from now to this time by (pseudo code) but idea should be clear

```
timeLeft = cachedDateTime - DateTime.now()
if(timeLeft<0){
show you page immediately and write to cache next time
}
else {
start timer with time left here
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. It may work. But I'd learn if Timer should have solved the problem, as it's a generic one with Future.delayed operation.